# How to create a macro that generates another macro in SISC / Scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, r5rs, guile, srfi

In Guile or using SRFI-46 it is possible like shown in [Specifying a Custom Ellipsis Identifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Syntax-Rules.html#Specifying-a-Custom-Ellipsis-Identifier). But is it possible in SISC or "pure scheme" R5RS?

I know it is possible without using ellipsis, but what if I need to use inner ellipsis like the example bellow?

```
(define-syntax define-quotation-macros
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (macro-name head-symbol) ...)
     (begin (define-syntax macro-name
              (syntax-rules ::: ()
                ((_ x :::)
                 (quote (head-symbol x :::)))))
            ...))))
(define-quotation-macros (quote-a a) (quote-b b) (quote-c c))
(quote-a 1 2 3) ⇒ (a 1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro expander used in SISC, psyntax, supports a different way to do inner ellipses, by using the `...` macro. You can write this by applying the `...` macro to each inner ellipses you want to use:

```
(define-syntax define-quotation-macros
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (macro-name head-symbol) ...)
     (begin (define-syntax macro-name
              (syntax-rules ()
                ((_ x (... ...))
                 '(head-symbol x (... ...)))))
            ...))))
```

or you can apply it to an outer form where all the ellipses within are supposed to be inner:

```
(define-syntax define-quotation-macros
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (macro-name head-symbol) ...)
     (begin (define-syntax macro-name
              (... (syntax-rules ()
                     ((_ x ...)
                      '(head-symbol x ...)))))
            ...))))
```